# Autocomplete in Lombardi 7.5

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to implement autocomplete feature in lombardi but i am facing issues as in how to pass the input that i enter in the textbox to the query to fetch the records via the source attribute using jquery ?

Comment: ever had a look at the demo? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote, http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have implemented following fetaure in 7.5 So can you clearly mention your requirement.. Sure i will help